# editing a netcdf variable

Tags: matlab, indexing, netcdf

I have a 3 dimensional variable `my_var` within a **netcdf** (original.nc) file (150x100x20000). I want to convert all of the elements within this variable from Celsius to Kelvin and then rewrite the variable's new values in a copy (test.nc) of the original file.

```
%make a copy of the file I’m editing (so I can write the new values to it later
copyfile('original.nc','test.nc');
%gets the attributes of the file
fileattrib('test.nc','+w');
%get id and opens the file for editing
ncid=netcdf.open('test.nc','WRITE');
%gets variable id and specifies the original variable for editing
varid=netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'my_var');
my_var=ncread('original.nc','my_var');
%converts the data from celcius to kelvin
new_myvar=convtemp(my_var,'C','K'); 
netcdf.putVar(ncid,varid,new_myvar);
netcdf.close(ncid);
```

I can't get the `new_myvar` variable to write over the original variable properly. The conversion to Kelvin is occurring correctly as far as I can tell: so the `new_myvar` variable is correct.
I think it has to do with the indexing..but I'm not sure.
I tried:

```
[dimname0,dimlength0]=netcdf.inqDim(ncid,0);
[dimname1,dimlength1]=netcdf.inqDim(ncid,0);
[dimname2,dimlength2]=netcdf.inqDim(ncid,0);
netcdf.putVar(ncid,testid,new_myvar,[0,0,0],[dimlength0-1,dimlength1-1,dimlength2-1]);
```

thinking that this would specify how many dimensions (and how many elements (the count)) needed to be filled. But it's not rewriting the variable correctly.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that the file is wrong, or is the actual variable wrong? If it's the former, maybe you need to call `ncwrite`?

Comment: the variable elements themselves are wrong. i.e. the newly converted data (in Kelvin) is not being transferred correctly from 'new_myvar' (where the elements are correct) to the 'myvar' variable in 'test.nc'

Comment: The netcdf.* functions and the nc* functions provide two different kinds of interfaces. You ought to be able to do this with just ncread, ncinfo, ncwriteschema and ncwrite. See if this code makes sense as a starting point: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31183-nc3to4/content/nc3to4.m

Comment: I'm fairly new to using .nc files. @Ashish are you suggesting that netcdf* functions should be avoided as a starting point? I used ncwrite, 'ncwrite('test.nc','my_var','new_myvar')'. It appears to have worked except for the fill values which were treated is NaNs in new_myvar, but have been replaced as zeros in the final edited 'myvar'.

Comment: Yes. nc* functions ought to be much easier to use initially. NetCDF has attributes which control the fill values. See if you can find it with an ncdisp on your source file. ncinfo and ncwriteschema can be used to transfer these attributes over to a new file. Have a look at the doc and see if you can figure it out, post back if you run into issues or if you figure it out.. post it as an answer :)

Comment: I've had a look at what you suggested @Ashish..I'm wondering are you suggesting then I skip the 'copy the file' step? then create the new file with the same attributes as the original, and finally populate the variable with the data afterwards? The ncwriteschema produces the same .nc attributes as the 'copyfile' does.i.e. the fill values are the same. Why then do you think that the NaNs are replaced by zeros after 'ncwrite('test.nc','my_var','new_myvar')'