# why does ncwrite replace all the NaN values with zero?

Tags: netcdf

This is a follow on from this topic ([editing a netcdf variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362906/editing-a-netcdf-variable)) using the approach suggested.
I want to create a new .nc file with data converted from Celsius to Kelvin. I used the convtemp function to convert an array of data (temp) from Celsius to Kelvin (newtemp) and tried to write the data to the file 'converted.nc') using ncwrite.

```
myschema=ncinfo('originalfile.nc');
ncwriteschema(newfile.nc',myschema);
newtemp=convtemp(temp,'C','K');
ncwrite('newfile.nc','temp',newtemp);
```

the temp is being converted and stored correctly in 'newtemp', however it is not being written correctly to the .nc file. the kelvin values seem to be off by 100 (but with no multiplier specified at the start of the array) AND the NaN values have all been replaced by zeros. Does anyone know how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

There some data structures which does not support 'NaN', because it's not a 'real' integer. It may be that you have encountered such a problem and that 0's are being used to still make the rest of the file usable despite encountering an invalid entry?